# How do you use 〜と知る?

Tags: grammar, nuances, particle-と

I've often seen and heard the expression `〜と知る（知っている）`.  When I think about it, it makes sense in the context of the quoatation-と, like with `〜と言う` or `〜と思う`.  It seems like it means "Know **that** 〜".

> ミユキちゃんが結婚したと知ってる？　→　Did you know that Mikyuki got married?

However, the few times I've tried to use it, I was told I was using it incorrectly, and that I should instead use `〜こと／のを知る`.

> ミユキちゃんが結婚したこと／のを知ってる？

So what are the rules for using `〜と知る`?  Do `〜と知る` and `〜こと／のを知る` have different meanings and rules (they seem the same to me)?

---

**Update**:  I've found quite a few examples from my Bible.  It's the `新共同訳` version, and I was able to [search it here](http://www.bible.or.jp/vers_search/vers_search.cgi).  I searched for `～と知る`, `～と知って`, and `～と知った`.  Here are a couple examples:

> - 「群衆は、イエスも弟子たちも**そこにいないと知る**と、自分たちもそれらの小舟に乗り、イエスを捜し求めてカファルナウムに来た。」　－　ヨハネによる福音書 / 6章 24節
> - 「けれども、人は律法【りっぽう】の実行ではなく、ただイエス・キリストへの信仰によって**義とされると知って**、わたしたちもキリスト・イエスを信じました」　－　ガラテヤの信徒への手紙 / 2章 16節
> - 「ヨナタンは言った。『そのような事は決してない。父があなたに危害を加える**決心をしていると知ったら**、必ずあなたに教えよう。』」　－　サムエル記上 / 20章 9節

Comment: I would interpret all of these as と（言うのを）. In colloquial this would be って.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The examples are very interesting. It looks like, whenever `と知る` can be used, it means "find out" rather than "know". Another way to say this is, whenever `と知る` can be used, you can replace the verb with `分かる`. With "find out", you cannot have duration, in other words, you can say:

> I knew that theorem **for two days**, (but I forgot it).

but you cannot say

> * I found out that theorem **for two days**.

the aspectuality matters. Applying this to Japanese, you can use `と知る` with a simple tense (under which `知る` means "find out"):

> 風の知らせで、みゆきちゃんが結婚したと知った。

but not with perfect (under which `知る` means "know"):

> * 昨日から、みゆきちゃんが結婚したと知っている。

And indeed this makes sense because `と` (similar to "to") implies the goal of change of location/state of something. Finding out something is a change of state, but knowing something is not.

Comment: This is a great answer. What do you think about "と知りながら" (e.g. "奥さん自身嘘と知りながらそうおっしゃるんでしょう")?

Comment: I think that you are approaching some truth, but I do not completely agree with what you wrote.  For example, in 来週君が来る[と/ことを]知っていれば、この時期に出張なんか入れなかったのに, both と and ことを sound natural to me although it uses the form 知っている.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I agree with your judgement. Maybe my description about ている was wrong. But in your example, it can be replaced with 分かる, so that part of my answer is correct, I think.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: then does my original made-up example sound natural at all to you?  `ミユキちゃんが結婚したと知ってる？`

Comment: @istrasci: I cannot explain why, but ミユキちゃんが結婚したと知ってる? does not sound very natural to me.  It should be ミユキちゃんが結婚した[の/こと]を知ってる?, as others noted.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto:  Hmm, I see.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping this concept. so for instance, what exactly does this line mean `ハッピーエンドばかりじゃないと知ってはいたけど`

Comment: @Mel I know that it is not always happy ending.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, It might be a little different. ～していれば　～した／～していた is an unrealistic condition. Maybe と often implies some kind of subjective judgement, e.g. と見る, と見なす, とする, と考える, etc. which makes it inappropriate with the simple stative 知っている.

Answer (score 0):

> ミユキちゃんが結婚したと知ってる？

This sentence is grammatically correct but not natural.

> ミユキちゃんが結婚した**って**知ってる？

This one is natural. In modern Japanese conversation, it does 促音便化 in this case.
But, the old style is also still in use even in conversation.

> ミユキちゃんが結婚したと知らされた。

So, here is the problem. "知ってる?" is quite informal, but "したと" is quite formal. That difference makes us uncomfortable.