# used of と侮る in these sentence and ~と侮る vs ~を侮る (perhaps related to 知る as well)

Tags: particle-と, particle-を

speaker is someone that normally fights demons, but fell for a trap
set up by A, a human. Speaker has always hated A.

> 私としたことが……相手が、魔族じゃないと……Aごときと侮って、視野が狭くなってた…… pass out
>
> I, of all people.... A...isn't a demon....underestimating (someone) like A, I became conceited.

[from what i can tell ~と侮る seems common as ~を侮る](http://yourei.jp/%E3%81%A8%E4%BE%AE%E3%82%8B)

from [「たかが過換気」と侮ってはいけない](https://medical.nikkeibp.co.jp/leaf/mem/pub/cadetto/practice/yueki/201712/552564.html), i assume that this is used as a quote to describe the preceeding claused just like ["ミユキちゃんが結婚した"と知ってる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5236/how-do-you-use-%e3%81%a8%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8b)

are both 相手が、魔族じゃない**と** and Aごとき**と** attached to 侮って or is it 「相手が、魔族じゃないと……Aごとき」と侮って?

more generally

If a random sentence had ~を侮る instead of ~と侮る, i probably wouldn't bat an eye. I suppose i could say the same for ~と知る vs ~を知る. CTRL-F'ing my past texts i found を知る is used 5x more often than と知る。

After this encountering this ~と侮る sentence i realized i really can't tell the difference between ~と知る vs ~を知る either.

Thank you for any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(AをBと)侮る is one of the verbs that take both を and と and means "to (verb) A as B". The part marked by と can be a full quote (clause or mini-sentence), but it can be a bare noun or a noun phrase, too. As usual, both the を-part and the と-part may be omitted.

- [Difference between だと vs と before 認める](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55990/5010)
- [grammatical and semantic difference of "嘘と思う" and "嘘だと思う"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56540/5010)
- [Can を used with だ/です](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55158/5010)

> - Aを魔族じゃないと侮る
>     to make light of A as not being a *mazoku*
> - 人(だ)と侮る
>     to make light (of someone) as (being) a (mere) human being
> - 人を侮る
>     to make light of human beings
> - たかが過換気(だ)と侮る
>     (literally) to underestimate thinking it's mere hyperventilation / to underestimate hyperventilation
> - [×] たかが過換気を侮る (unnatural)
>     [×] to underestimate mere hyperventilation (sounds like you have to underestimate something other than hyperventilation)

The difference between ～を知る and ～と知る is similar, but と usually takes a full quote (i.e., mini-sentence with a verb). In fixed expressions and literary expressions, `noun + と知る` exists.

Comment: does that meant one of theと in 相手が魔族じゃないと、Aごときと侮る is redundant?

Comment: @charu It's just two と's used in parallel, somewhat like a list. The first と can be dropped, but it will be harder to parse this sentence without it.