# とも in どこの馬の骨とも知らない

Tags: grammar

> どこの馬の骨とも知らない男

I am aware that「どこの馬の骨とも知らない」is an idiomatic phrase meaning "unknown" but what does it literally mean? "Not knowing whatever horse's bone"? What is the role of と before も? Is も connected to どこ?

Comment: 「どこの馬の骨とも知**れ**ない」だと思ってましたが・・

Comment: @Chocolate 間違いってことですか? これはある漫画から引いたものです。

Comment: さあ～～・・「知**ら**ない」でもいいのかな・・・？？わかりませんｗｗ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

知る actually can take と as a particle. For the difference between ～を知る and ～と知る, see this answer:

[How do you use 〜と知る?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5236/30454)

I don't fully agree with the answer though. I feel like the differentiation seems more complicated than presented in that answer, but the suggested test—try swapping in 分かる—is a good rule of thumb to go by. And I believe it's also common to hear 「どこの馬の骨とも分からないやつ」

This も just means "even", as in 「猿**も**木から落ちる」 ("Even monkeys fall from trees")

> どこの馬の骨とも知らない男
> a man whom we know nothing about, a total stranger, someone whose basic background we don't *even* know